# Ram unrecognized, sometimes

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm facing a hardware issue that is out of my field of expertise.

I have a `AM3 Gigabyte GA-880GM-UD2H` with 4 slots of DDR3 filled with 2GB of ram `G.Skill Kit Extreme3 2 x 2 Go 1600 MHz NQ PC 12800` (total : 8gb).

And I'm facing this odd issue :

Slot 2 works with two of my ram sticks, but with the other two, the computer starts with long beeps (as if there were no ram sticks installed). This, of course, occurs only when I put in one ram stick.

So I suspected that the ram stick was bad. But if I move that SAME ram stick to slot 3 or 4, the computer works correctly.

So I suspected that slot 2 is dead, but as said before, it works with 2 of 4 ram sticks.

The computer freezes from time to time, and when it freezes, I have to shut it down, cut the power to the computer, and play with the ram sticks until it decides to start working.

When that occurs, it either stops when calculating the size of the ram OR when searching for available disks.

I don't know if the issue is the RAM, the Motherboard, or even something else?

Here's my full configuration :

- Gigabyte GA-880GM-UD2H
- AMD Phenom™ II X6 1055T
- 2 x (2 x 4) G.Skill Kit Extreme3 2 x 2 Go PC12800 NQ
- OCZ ModXStream Pro - 600W
- Sapphire Radeon™ HD 5450 1Go
- SSD Corsair F40
- Western Digital Caviar Green S-ATA - 500 Go - 32 Mo

NB: The DVD has not worked for more than a year now, it appears that the motherboard don't detect it.

I have had this computer for more than 4 years now and never had an issue with the ram up until a few months ago.

Comment: Yes;  I would agree the problem is the motherboard.

Comment: Have you tried putting the ram into another computer and seeing what happens?

Comment: @TheKB no unfortunately I don't have an other computer to test on.

Comment: It would really help if you had another computer to test them on, but I would suspect that the motherboard is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with your ram slot (motherboard). Leave the bad ram slot empty and upgrade one ram stick so you can backup your lost ram.

Comment: man you're late! :) almost three years since I asked it. For information I did change the motherboard and the problem was fixed. Thank you :)